# No audio in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, asus

so lately i've installed from the USB ubuntu 18.04(previously had Windows 10) on my asus transformer and everything goes just fine except for the audio. I can't hear anything either from speakers either from headphones.
I'm new to ubuntu so at this point i don't know what i should do or not.
Please help me, i would be very grateful if you do.

Some info:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=877c6ed0d63852c1676d9096555b50c49d9fc1e6

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the sound driver is not installed. You'll need to check with your manufacturer about what sound card is in your device to find the correct driver, but you can try with the Intel Sound Driver (which is a common one) by running `sudo apt install firmware-intel-sound`.

You could also try enabling the Pulseaudio sound service if it is disabled by running `pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog`. (If it is disabled by default, you'll have to re-enter it every time the system reboots (or add it to the startup services with the "Startup Applications" program)).

The Pulseaudio volume control program lets you manage the sound with a graphical frontend. Install it with `sudo apt install pavucontrol`.

You can try re-installing the core sound packages with `sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio linux-sound-base libasound2`

If all of that fails, try killing the service with `killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*`, followed by a reboot.

Comment: Firslty i get an error with the first command by installing the driver.
i get sth like:
E: Unable to locate package firmware-intel-sound

And i guess the other command are useless if the first one doesn't work.
Anyway, i already have installed pauvcontrol, i also re=installed the core sound packages, still nothing.

Comment: Try the troubleshooting steps at https://support.system76.com/articles/audio/ they might be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i followed all the steps and in the command (aplay -l) i get the same error; aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found... , At this point i don't know what to do.

Comment: No sound cards found means it has not detected any sound card in your system. This could literally mean there is no sound card inside, but if sound works fine in Windows, it could mean that the manufacturer that made your sound card is not well known. You should contact Asus and ask them what sound card your device uses, they may be able to tell you.